# Getting a list of custom structures from command line with argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

So I have class `Foo`, that contains 3 fields: integers `start` and `end` and string `name`.

I want to get list of `Foo`s from argparse, using input like

`my_program --foo 5 7 first --foo 10 12 second`.

`parser.add_argument('--foo', action='append', default=[], nargs=2)` is quite close, it will return list of lists `[['5', '7', 'first'], ['10', '12', 'second']]`

I tried adding type=Foo, but it tries to convert each of the arguments instead.
`[[Foo('5'), Foo('7'), Foo('first')], ...]` and I want to perform conversion + validation inside argparse. Is it possible?

Comment: You might be able to do it with a custom `Action` subclass.  That sees the full list of values.  As you discovered the `type` is applied to each string separately.  But often it is simpler to do your own validation and conversion after parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? For the record I agree its easier and clearer to just validate after parsing.

```
import argparse


class foo():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

class CustomAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        foos.append(foo(*values))

foos = []
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', action=CustomAction, default=[], nargs=3)
parser.parse_args()

for x in foos:
    print(x.a, x.b, x.c)
```